# WPF MVVM User Control

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I am working on a WPF app using MVVM. On the main windows is a combo box of customer names. When a customer is selected I want to show the addresses for it.

So I created an Address user control and in the control's code behind I added a DP:

```
public static DependencyProperty CustomerIdProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("CustomerId", typeof(int), typeof(AddressView));

public int CustomerId
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(CustomerIdProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CustomerIdProperty, value);  }
}
```

Next, in the main window I bound the combo to the user control's CustomerId DP:

```
<vw:AddressView Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="0"
                x:Name="AddressList"
                CustomerId="{Binding ElementName=CustomersList, Path=SelectedCustomer.Id, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

I now have a problem and a question:

Problem: When I run this and select a customer, the setter on the DP never fires. The SelectedCustomer property in the Main Window fires, but not the DP in the user control.

Question: How does the ViewModel for the control know about the CustomerId in the DP?

I have created a small sample app here to demonstrate what I'm doing:

http://sdrv.ms/17OZv1x

I would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks

Comment: If the dependancy property is set via bindings the Get/Set will not be called, that is just for using in the local codebase, You can add a PropertyChangedCallback to your DependencyProperties MetaData if you need to check its is being assigned

Comment: Ok, I see. But that still doesn't answer the question of how the value of the CustomerID in the code behind gets to the ViewModel?

Comment: @kmarois: Via the binding system.  If you want to know how it works [start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752914(v=vs.110).aspx) and keep reading.

Answer (score 2):

instead of using dependency properties you can go an easy way when your customer object also has the address property

```
 <AdressView>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyAddress.Name}" />
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyAddress.Street}" />
```

mainwindow

```
  <ComboBox X:Name=cbo .../>
  <local:AddressView DataContext="{Binding ElementName=cbo, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

customer.cs

```
 public Address MyAddress {get;set;}
```

if you want your dependency property stuff to work, you have to post the code for your addressview, so that we can check the bindings to the dependency properties and you have to give some information how you wanna get the address with your customerid.

Answer (score 1):

`CustomerList` is of type `ComboBox` and a ComboBox has no property SelectedCustomer. The property you need for your binding is `SelectedItem`. *You should get binding errors during your debug session in Visual Studio. See Output Window*.

To get it work you need to update the binding of the CustomerId-Property to the following.

```
CustomerId="{Binding ElementName=CustomersList, Path=SelectedItem.Id}"
```

The TwoWay-Binding is only relevant if you want to change the `Id` from your `AddressView`. And I think that you don´t want it. So it can be removed.

Comment: The Combo is bound to a List<CustomerEntity>, and its SelectedItem property is bound to the SelectedCustomer property, which are both on the VM.