# WPF MVVM Bind User Control to Main Window View Model

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I asked a similar question a while back here [WPF MVVM User Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159580/wpf-mvvm-user-control). I got some answers, but they were way off, so I guess I wasn't clear in what I want to do....

I am working on a WPF application using MVVM. The app is built using a component based approach, so I have some user controls that I've defined that will be used throughout the application. As an example, I have an Address control. I want to use it an multiple places throughout the application. Here's an example. See here:

http://sdrv.ms/1aD775H

The part with the green border is the Address control. The control has its own View Model.

When I place it on a window or other control, I need to tell it the PK of the customer to load addresses for. So I created a Customer ID DependencyProperty:

```
public partial class AddressView : UserControl
{
    public AddressView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static DependencyProperty CustomerIdProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CustomerId", typeof(int), typeof(AddressView),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(0, AddressView.CustomerIdPropertyChangedCallback, AddressView.CustomerIdCoerce, true));


    public int CustomerId
    {
        // THESE NEVER FIRE
        get { return (int)GetValue(CustomerIdProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CustomerIdProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void CustomerIdPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // THIS NEVER FIRES
        AddressView instance = (AddressView)d;
        instance.CustomerId = (int)args.NewValue;
    }
    enter code here
    private static object CustomerIdCoerce(DependencyObject d, object value)
    {
        return value;   // <=== THIS FIRES ON STARTUP
    }
}
```

Then in the MainWindowView I have:

```
<vw:AddressView Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="0"
                x:Name="AddressList"
                CustomerId="{Binding ElementName=TheMainWindow, Path=SelectedCustomer.Id, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Note my comments in the user control's CS. The Coerce fires on startup. The callback never fires, nor do the CustomerId getter or setter.

What I would like to happen seems simple, I just can't make it work....

When a customer is selected the CustomerId should be passed to the Address UserControl. Then in the VM for the Address UserControl should handle getting & saving the data.

So, again, 2 questions:

1) Anyone see what's wrong?

2) How does the UserControl DP send the PK to the ViewModel?

If anyone's interested, my sample project is here: http://sdrv.ms/136bj91

Thanks

Comment: try adding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to your binding, when the selection changes your control won't get updated otherwise.

Comment: can you post code of your usercontrol xaml page..

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF MVVM User Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159580/wpf-mvvm-user-control)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
CustomerId="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.YourSelectedItem.TheProperty}"
```

I am not sure how to manage your seleted item in window, so please change `yourSelectedItem.TheProperty` accordingly.

Comment: Ok, this worked - but only once. The callback method only fire the first time a Customer is selected.

Comment: can you paste the implementation of your SelectedItem in code

Comment: Sure, I created a small sandbox project to learn this. It's here http://sdrv.ms/13fM5EY.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CustomerId` getter and setter will never fire in this situation. They are there simply as helper methods in case *you* want to access the `CustomerIdProperty` property from your code behind.

Your `CustomerIdPropertyChangedCallback` method will not fire because your binding expression is incorrect. You need to bind to the `DataContext` of `MainWindow` and not the window itself:

```
...
CustomerId="{Binding ElementName=TheMainWindow, Path=DataContext.SelectedCustomer.Id}"
...
```

Also, make sure that you are calling the `INotifyPropertyChanged` `PropertyChanged` event when the property bound to the `ComboBox` is changed.